# How can I enable CSRF protection in the pop-up login/register forms in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, csrf, csrf-protection

I am using a CodeIgniter script which has the following to clarify this is the full code for the login form in a modul

```
    <!-- modal login -->
 <div id="login" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog white-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
 <p id="myModalLabel"><i class="icon icon-user"></i> Login </p>
 </div><!-- modal-header -->
  <div class="modal-body">
   <?php if (isset($login_message)) {
    echo $login_message;
}

 ?>

  <form method="post" action="/users/login" class="form" id="login-form">

    <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="username" class="form-control" /><br/>
    <input type="password" name="upwd" placeholder="****" class="form-control" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="sbLogin" value="<?=_('Login')?>" class="btn btn-black"/>
    <a href="/home/lostpassword" class="btn btn-default">Lost Password</a><br />
    <br /><div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="small" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
    <br /><br />Don't have an Account? <a href="/?signup=yes">Create one</a>

  </form>
  <br />
  <div id="login_output_div"></div>
  </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
   <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
 </div>
 </div><!-- .modal dialog -->
```

To protect the form can I add

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?=$csrf['name'];?>" value="<?=$csrf['hash'];?>" />
```

and use

```
$csrf = array(
    'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
    'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
);
```

in the header of the page after enabling CSRF in the config? Will doing so mess up my other forms and will I need to add this to every form?

```
 <input type="hidden" name="<?=$csrf['name'];?>" value="<?=$csrf['hash'];?>" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to open this file:

```
application/config/config.php
```

Then set the CSRF to true

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = true;
```

then go to this file
`application/config/autoload.php`

add `form` to array item called `helper`

`$autoload['helper'] = array('form');`

Then you should use the form helper in codeigniter, which you can read about it in this link:

[codeigniter form helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

It does add the csrf and validates it for you.

Then on your view, you can simple use:

```
<?php $attributes = array('id' => 'login-form');
echo form_open('/users/login', $attributes); ?>
```

it will automatically create `<form>` tag and adds the csrf to it, then once this form is submitted, the csrf will be validated by codeigniter, and if the csrf was successful, the code will resume, otherwise, it will fail and gives you error message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have tried replacing my code 

         <form method="post" action="/users/login" class="form" id="login-form">


but I get this error 

      Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function form_open() in /home/techhptz/samuiauctions.online/application/views/header.php:138

Comment: to use `form_open()` you first need to load CI's form helper in your controller (or in a construct)